# Why does switch take a noun in the plural?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality

Why do we say "We switched locations." or "We switched phones." instead of "We switched location?" or "We switched phone?"

Are there any other verbs that take the noun in the plural?

Comment: Any and all transitive verbs can take a noun in the plural. I can love muffins, tie shoes, buy lobsters, change clothes, kick puppies, steal bracelets, lend cars, post comments, close questions, drink beers, cook books, smoke cigarettes and suck balls. And that's just one typical afternoon. Whether the noun is plural depends on the noun and not the verb. This case here is not different in that it takes a plural, but in that it can't take a singular. But that's, again, because there's always at least two of the thing you are switching. *Exchange* works the same way.

Comment: Are there any other verbs that take the noun in the plural? *"We changed trains"*; *"we traded shots"*; *"we joined hands"*; *"we swapped stories"*; *"we pooled resources"*; *"we mixed chemicals"* *"we exchanged phone numbers"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegDwight has it. When you "switch" that means there are at least 2 or more of whatever you're talking about. In your examples you say, "We switched locations." To switch from one location to another, there needs to be at least two of them. Same with phones or whatever else you'd like to switch from one to another. You can't switch with just one object!

Answer (score 0):

One might think that

1. when switch means 'change from one thing to another', it can be followed by a singular noun: *Andrew had first followed John the Baptist and then switched allegiance to Jesus. *( *U.S. Catholic* )

and

2. When switching involves one person exchanging something with another person, we can use  a plural noun: *In one of Essany's skits, he switched jobs with Valparaiso mayor David Butterfield* .(*Christian Science Monitor*)

A superficial examination of COCA citations for both singular and plural nouns suggests that this might be true of the singular form. However, there is some inconsistency with the plural, with such sentences as *I switched schools to move to a larger school district for more pay*. (*Music Educators Journal*)